# How to change the array source for a spinner? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio, spinner

I have asked this before, but I was too general.

I have an activity with two radio buttons and only two arrays: `String[] tickets;` which has 3 items and `String[] subscriptions;` which has 5 items. By the way, the radio buttons are inside a radioGroup.

The first radioButton is for `String[] tickets;` and the second radioButton is for `String[] subscriptions;`

When I check the first radioButton, I want the spinner to be populated by the items in `String[] tickets` and when I check the second radioButton I want the spinner to be populated by the items in `String[] subscriptions;`

But how do you do that? I tried using a temporary array which is empty and used it as the array source for the spinner. I would then place one of these arrays inside the empty one. But it did not work.

EDIT:

```
MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

   String[] tickets = {"Ticket #1", "Ticket #2", "Ticket #3"};
   String[] subscriptions = {"Sub #1", "Sub #2", "Sub #3", "Sub #4", "Sub #5"};
   String[] tempArray;
   Spinner spinner1;
   RadioGroup radioGroup;
   RadioButton radioButtonOption;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);

   radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
   int selectedRadioButton = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
   radioButtonOption = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedRadioButton);
   spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);


   radioButtonOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         if (radioButtonOption.getText().equals("Journeys/Tickets")) {
            tempArray = tickets;
         } else if (radioButtonOption.getText().equals("Subscription")) {
            tempArray = subscriptions;
         }
      }
   });

   spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
   ArrayAdapter a1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, tempArray);
   a1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
   spinner1.setAdapter(a1);
   spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: What you have tried so far can you show us your code?

Comment: @PraveenSP Of course! And hello. I remember you helped me :)))

Comment: @PraveenSP I updated the post. This is all that I've tried until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
        radioGroup = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch (checkedId)
                {
                    case  R.id.button_1:
                        a1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item ,tickets);
                        spinner1.setAdapter(a1);
                        break;

                    case R.id.button_2:
                        a1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,subscriptions);
                        spinner1.setAdapter(a1);
                        break;

                }

                a1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            }
        });

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Note you need to declare `ArrayAdapter a1;`

Comment: Everything looks good, but Android Studio underlines an error for the following line of code: `(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,tickets)` It says: Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(anonymous android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener, int, java.lang.String[ ])'

Comment: You need to pass YourActivityName.this as first parameter to resolve ambiguity Suppose your activity name is MyActivity then you need to pass MyActivity.this

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works perfectly now. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem man You are welcome.. and Thanks for remembering it's meant a lot to me. I really appreciate it. And Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can call OnCheckChangeListener on your radioGroup and then set spinner adapter accordingly. See the example:

```
a1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);               
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

  switch(checkedId){
       case R.id.radio_button1:
                      a1 = ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,tickets);
                      spinner1.setAdapter(a1);
                      break;
       case R.id.radio_button2:
                      a1 = ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,subscriptions);
                      spinner1.setAdapter(a1);
                      break;               
   }
 }
});
```

Comment: But where do I put `a1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(a1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);` ?

Comment: Updated the answer in Java. It will work and cover all your code.

Comment: Thank you! But it still shows an error at this part: (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,tickets)

Comment: Pass MainActivity.this instead of this as the first argument.

Comment: Thank you very much AlphaOne! It works perfectly now. You and Praveen helped a lot. Thank you :))